# How can I make instance variables availble for models for computation and then return the result to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I understand instance variables in controller getting data from the model and displaying to the view. How can I send instance variables to the model though? I want to run computations on the variable and send it back to the view updated by the model.

Comment: Just pass them as method parameters.

Comment: I am new, Please elaborate. What do you mean? Please provide an example since I am a total noob in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just pass controller instance vars to the model as method arguments. Here's an example:

```
# model
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def run_computations var1, var2
    # perform complex computations
    [var1 * 2, var2 * 3]
  end
end


# controller
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def my_action
    @var1 = 10
    @var2 = 20

    @var1, @var2 = MyModel.run_computations @var1, @var2
    # MyModel.run_computations returns an array. The line above is a shortcut for
    #   picking the array apart. It is equivalent to this
    # arr = MyModel.run_computations @var1, @var2
    # @var1 = arr[0]
    # @var2 = arr[1]
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorta get it but confused: I am from the java world. So let me explain what i understand and please correct me if I am wrong:  So in the action "my_action", you are calling method defined in the model. You initialize instance variables with the integer 10. I don't understand what this is at all:                  **var1, var2 = MyModel.run_computations var1, var2**            Is the view going to see the 10 and 10 or is the view going to see 10*2, and 10*3.. Can you give a more traditional example with less ruby specific syntax, not really sure what this array assignment is about at all..

Comment: @user836087: there's an explanation of array assignment below.

Comment: @user836087: after that line `@var1` will equal 20 (10 * 2) and `@var2` will equal 60 (20 * 3)